# Upload Video to Youtube in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, youtube-api, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to upload a video to Youtube from a Windows Store App (C# + XAML).
The authentication part was quite easy using OAuth. But the upload itself is not so easy.
I'm really stuck and have no idea where to go next.
In typical .Net application you can use the "google-gdata" client Library, but it doesn't work on Windows Store Apps.

Has anyone tried this before? And succeed? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to upload video file yourself. May be this [HttpClient sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664) can be handy to start with. Again Laurent has a [helpful talk](http://vimeo.com/53068482) with MVVM light

Comment: Yea, the HttpClient sample was the way to go... Using the Http post Multipart Example and keeping an eye on the Youtube API 2.0 [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading#Sending_a_Direct_Upload_API_Request) I was able to get this working.

Comment: Now, it would be nice to have a way to know the progress of the upload (know how many bytes are left to upload for example).
I know it's easy if we use the BackgroundUploader, but that's not the case here...